# Are RingCT transaction bigger than an average ring signature transaction?

Tags: ringct, ring-signatures

Are RingCT transaction bigger than an average ring signature transaction?

If yes how much bigger?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they are a bit in practice, but according to the RingCT paper of Shen Noether on http://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1098 it seems it cannot be much:

[image]
[image]